# Vector calculation question...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

in the formula for the calulation of the angle between 2 vectors

$$\cos \theta \overset{\text{def}}= \dfrac{\vec\alpha \cdot \vec\beta}{|\vec \alpha|\cdot |\vec \beta|}$$

is the output angle is always the smaller of the two angles which are between the vectors? what happens if I get a larger than 90 degrees angle?

Comment: I'm not understanding what you're trying to ask: Are you asking if the angle between 2 vectors is the smallest of the angles each vector makes with the positive x-axis? And what do you mean by your second question: If the dot product of the two vectors is negative, then $\theta$ will be in the range $[\pi/2, \pi]$, so the angle will be greater than $90$.

Comment: yes thats correct, the angle should alwyas be the smaller of the two and hence what do you do if you get the larger one..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The angle you get most straightforwardly (by applying arcos to the expression on the right hand side) will be an angle between 0 and $\pi $ radians (0 and 180 degrees), so it may well be larger than 90 degrees. This is because the expression may be negative, which comes from the cosine of an obtuse angle.

With this formula, you get the angle between the *vectors*, the one made by joining the two vectors at their tail ends and looking at the angle from the head of one vector to the intersection of their tails to the head of the other vector. This may be acute, right, or obtuse. If you look at the orientation of the vectors you may even get a negative angle, but this formula does not distinguish between positive and negative angle, since cosine is an even function. If orientation matters, you would use something such as the cross product, rather than the dot product, to find the orientation.

Comment: the cross product gives out a vector not an angle

Comment: Yes, but the sign of the z component gives the orientation of the two vectors in the x-y plane. By the right-hand rule, if the z component of $\overrightarrow \alpha \times \overrightarrow \beta$ is positive, $\overrightarrow \beta$ is clockwise from $\overrightarrow \alpha$, and if it is negative then counterclockwise.

Comment: I see, but the peoblem is that the ngle between vectors whihc is taken is always the smaller one, but what do you do if you get the larger one...

Comment: we were expinaed it may indicate a mistake in calculation

Comment: What do you mean "the [a]ngle between vectors whi[ch] is taken is always the smaller one"? That is not usually true for vectors, as I said in my second paragraph. If you want the smaller angle between the *lines* defined by the vectors, you could use the cross product (since arcsine gives an acute, is possibly negative, angle). You could also use the cosine formula and just take its supplementary angle if you get an obtuse angle.

Comment: I'll explain myself ; we were tasked with finding the angle betwen two vectros and I got a larger than 90 degree while the answer key suggests it's complementry as the answer, so my question is, do I take 180 - alpha for instance or is there some miskate in the caclulations I made?

Comment: I would need to see the actual problem you were given, but my guess is that you made a calculation mistake. The other possibility is your book uses a weird definition for the angle between two vectors, and I doubt that. I don't know how to go to chat for us to discuss this further.

Comment: yeah but doesnt that mean they just took the smaller angle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15777/discussion-between-rory-daulton-and-bak1139).